# Compute your payoff for the game and decide if it's worth playing

Tags: probability

Suppose you are offered to play the following game: with probability 0.20 you win and receive  $\text{\$}$40
and with probability 0.80 you lose $\text{\$}$5. The fee of playing the game is $1. What is the expected payoff
after you deduct the fee? Will you accept the game?

My solution: $0.20\cdot 40 + 0.80 \cdot (-5) = 8 - 4 - 1 = \text{\$}3$. So, yes, I'd accept the game.  I guess the outcomes  - win / yes are independent, that's why we can sum the probabilities together. The idea of payoff still doesn't make sense to me, because one can either win or lose, so why sum them together. How these types of problems are formalised?

Comment: Curiously, you have neither computed a probability nor have you summed probabilities: you are calculating an *expectation.*  Are you familiar with some definition of this term and are you conversant with its linearity property?

Comment: @whuber My bad, but how is payoff usually computed, is it expected value or something else?

Comment: "Expectation" and "expected value" are synonyms.

Comment: @whuber I know, but I just don't know if I computed the payoff correctly or not.